# Is it bad to serve XHTML rather than HTML?

Tags: html, web, xhtml, compatibility

Why don't more sites serve XHTML? I see the use self-closing tags and the ability to more easily minify pages as fair advantages. Are there any big downsides to doing it this way? Is there a risk that some browsers may still not like the self-closing syntax? And is "text/xml" the content type I should be using?

Comment: Not bad, just different. Choose what works for you. But which-ever you use, use the appropriate content type.

Comment: What ability to minify pages? HTML is much shorter on average, especially when you want your page to validate as XHTML 1.x in the W3C validator (Longer DOCTYPE, more required attributes etc).

Comment: Not that I dislike XHTML, mind you. I like the fact that it shows me instantly if I have structural errors. Anyway, to answer your second question, as far as I'm aware many people still use IE8 today, so if you want to cater to everybody, make sure to check the browser's http-accept.

Answer (score 1):

The correct content type for XHTML is `application/xhtml+xml`. But really, unless you need XML compliance, there is a pretty standard way to parse HTML, and there're many HTML parsers you can choose from, and both compress pretty well.

So, in other words, many sites don't believe that XHTML adds enough value to use it.

Answer (score 1):

XHTML is not "HTML that looks like XML". It's XML with a predefined set of element types, and serving it as anything other than an application of XML renders it completely pointless from a technical point of view.

Answer (score -1):

Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp
It explains what is the difference between HTML and XHTML.

> Are there any big downsides to doing it this way?

In my opinion, when you write code of any kind, you want to know exactly what is does. If you use self closing tags, that might be a problem when it closes when you don't want it to. For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>This is a self closing paragraph.
<!-- a bunch of content -->
</p><!-- some stray tag you accidentally wrote -->
<!-- Now all of the code from the first tag to the last tag is a paragraph! -->
</body>
</html>
```

It might be worse when you use some tag that is more harmful that `<p>`. What if it is `<a href="img/cute_kitten.jpg">`? Your entire page will be a link inviting the user to look at kittens!
Therefore, always use closing tags.

Comment: Probably your link to W3Schools. People believe that links to W3Schools are always bad, even to pages that aren't.

Comment: I don't really see your point. Of course if you write some code that is wrong, it's wrong. Maybe I personally just am not in the habit of not closing my tags properly, but I just don't see how this is a very real concern. It would seem like real XML/XHTML, with its more terse syntax, would be more conducive to writing clear, mistake-free code.

Comment: Okay then... but I always want to be sure my code works (on every browser, don't know in this case).